# UItableView load data on scroll

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my app I am getting the data from the web-service and I have to display it in UITableView.
But the condition here is I have to display only 10 records initially,then once the user scroll down I have to load more records.I tried searching it but didn't get any useful answer.
I agree that I will use -

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

to display the value,but how will I fetch only 10 records from the service and then other record based on scroll.
Please provide some pointers or sample code.

Thanks

Comment: what about trying lazyLoading concept ?

Comment: No I donot want to implement lazy loading,I wanted 10 record to be loaded at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case if some one need it,i was able to solve my problem this way.
First thing is you need the server configuration in such a way so that it should return 10 data at a time based on the row which is visible in TableView.
This is the tableView delegate which get called and returns the visible cells in tableView

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        int lastRow=[nameArray count]-1;
        if(([indexPath row] == lastRow)&&(lastRow<[categoryArray count]))  
        {

            if(tableView==m_pDetailsTableView)    {
                savedScrollPosition=lastRow;
                startCellValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0];
                endCellValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[nameArray count]+10];
                [self connectToServer]; //Method to request to server to get more data
            }
        }
    }
```

savedscrollPosition variable stores the variable as a point where you want to scroll the table view after load of data.

Answer (score 7):

You should read about lazy loading. The code is available at Apple's website. Download it here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

check the code of

```
- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
```

method.

It uses the same approach you need. It gets the current scroll position of the table view and on the basis of that, it will get the cells displayed on the screen and their indexPath. On the basis of that you will be able to show those cells which are shown in the screen.

For showing 10 rows, a simple calculation is required.

Comment: Yes I agree,I can apply the logic for displaying it but for this also I will have to load the entire data from web-service at once.?
I wanted to fetch 10 record from the service and display.

Comment: NO , not entire data, just those data which belong to the cell displayed on the screen at a time. so First on viewing table load the 10 records that you are asked for. after that only fetch those records whose cell is being shown on the screen. Lazy loading means load only that info which is required , NOT ENTIRE DATA.

Comment: If you could joim chat at chat room "iPhone " , we can discuss in detail. It will be my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 4):

Just insert the new data into your datasource
see below

If you're using xml - check out XMLReader - [turn XML into an NSDictionary](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)
this sample code below uses AFNetworking (which is non blocking)
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        [self fetchMoreData];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self fetchMoreData];
}


- (void)fetchMoreData
{

    if ([resultArray count] > 0)
    {
       NSArray *visiblePaths = [myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
       NSIndexPath *lastRow = [visiblePaths lastObject];

        // Check whether or not the very last row is visible.
        NSInteger numberOfSections = [myTableView numberOfSections];
        NSInteger lastRowSection = [lastRow section];
        NSInteger lastRowRow = [lastRow row];
        NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastRowSection];

        if (lastRowSection == numberOfSections - 1 &&  
            lastRowRow== numberOfRowsInSection - 1) {

            DLog(@"it's the last row");
            if ([resultArray count]%10 == 0) { // use a divider based on your pagination
               [self fetchNextPage];
            }

        }
    }
}


-(void)getFeeds{
    ENTER_METHOD;

    [resultArray removeAllObjects];
    //reset this
   NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/webserviceurl.xml?offset=0"];
    [httpClient getPath:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        [self parseFeedsXMLString:operation.responseString];
        //  offset = offset + 10; // ONLY if there's results increment

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSString *detailError=nil;
     }];

}

-(void)fetchNextPage{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/webserviceurl.xml?offset=%d",offset];
    [httpClient getPath:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        DLog(@"operation.responseString:%@",operation.responseString);
        [self parseNextFeedsXMLString:operation.responseString];
       // offset = offset + 10; // ONLY increment if there's results 


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    }];

}



- (void)parseFeedsXMLString:(NSString *)xmlString
{

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlString error:&parseError];
    DLog(@"xmlDictionary:%@",xmlDictionary);
    resultArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"]]retain];

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)parseNextFeedsXMLString:(NSString *)xmlString
{

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlString error:&parseError];
    DLog(@"xmlDictionary:%@",xmlDictionary);
    //[resultArray insertObject:e atIndex:[resultArray count]];

    NSMutableArray *results  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"]];

    if ([results count]) {
        page++;
        for (NSDictionary  *dict in results) {
            [resultArray insertObject:dict atIndex:[results count]];
        }

    }
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question ,you can do the following.

> 1 ) implement scrollViewDidScroll
>
> 2 ) check for visible rows in that
>
> 3 ) if you found the last row just call the web service for loading
>   more data
>
> 4 ) on getting the data just reload the table

Try it .

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the return value of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`  method, every time you want to insert ten rows, you can plus 10 to the return value.

sorry for my poor english.

Comment: But still I will have to load the entire data in the array at a time.Right..?But I want to fetch 10 records and display.

Comment: I think the problem is common; You can request lots of records per time(more than 10); but you can adjust the numberOf*** to control the cell number in the tableView, when you scroll to bottom, you can insert another 10 cells more, if the records is not in local, another request for new recordes to web-server is needed.

Comment: Thats right Yebw.I want another request to made to the webserver to fetch another 10 record.Any idea how to do that just to fetch 10 records.

Comment: It is your communication protocol with server must supports, I think

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
    i = i +10;
    NSString *unescaped = mySearchBar.text;
    NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [PServiceAPI searchKeyWord:escapedString withOffSet:i Handler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            [arBase addObjectsFromArray:results];
            [myTableView2 reloadData];

        }
    }];

  }
}
```